# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python

I have this error coming up everytime I run this query I am trying to import csv to mysql this is my csv file

```
2880,H3KZV,2014/06/24 09:34:28,2014/06/25 09:34:28,1280
2880,R9UZB,2014/06/24 10:34:05,2014/06/24 16:34:05,1340
```

I get this error on ticket price.(1280,1340) # i have removed most of the  code

this is my query:

```
  for row in reader:
        print row
        try:
            (location_id, vrm, start_datetime,end_datetime) = [x.decode('utf-8-sig') for x in row]
        except:
            print "Error with row: " % row

            tmp = start_datetime.split(" ")
        start_date = tmp[0]

       tmp = end_datetime.split(" ")
        end_date = tmp[0]

        tmp = start_date.split('/')
        tmp = end_date.split('/')
        SesionCost = ticket_price /100

        iso_date = "%s-%s-%s" % (tmp[0], tmp[1], tmp[2])
        entryDatetime = "%s 00:00:00 " % iso_date
        expiryDatetime = "%s 23:59:59" % iso_date
        sql_local = """INSERT INTO customer_1.pay_and_display
            (plate, machine_id, ticket_datetime, expiry_datetime, ticket_name, ticket_price)
            VALUES ("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s") """ % (vrm, location_id, entryDatetime, expiryDatetime, "RINGOtest", 0)
        print sql_local
        cursor.execute(sql_local)
        curl = pycurl.Curl()
        body = Body()
   payload = [("fn", "addWhitelistEntryValue"),
            ("firstname", "WL"),
            ("startDate", start_date.encode('ascii', 'ignore')),
            ("startTime", "00:00:00"),
            ("endDate", end_date.encode('ascii', 'ignore')),
            ("endTime", "23:59:59"),
            ("vrm", vrm.encode('ascii', 'ignore')),
            ("locId", location_id.encode('ascii', 'ignore')),
            ("ticket_price",ticket_price.encode('ascii','ignore'))
]
```

Comment: Better provide full working example. Small details like what you import from make the difference, if you allow us copy paste your code and run, it is easy, if not, we have to guess and might miss.

Comment: I have changed my query that would give you some idea.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ticket_price = float (ticket_price)/100
>     ...
> ("ticket_price",ticket_price.encode('ascii','ignore' ))
> ```

*How exactly did you imagine this would work?*

Comment: I have solved it myself i just blocked that statment.

Answer (score 0):

SessionCost = float(ticket_price)/ 100.0

```
iso_date = "%s-%s-%s" % (tmp[0], tmp[1], tmp[2])
entryDatetime = "%s %s "  % (iso_date, start_time)
expiryDatetime = "%s %s " % (iso_date, end_time)
sql_local = """INSERT INTO customer_1.pay_and_display
    (plate, machine_id, ticket_datetime, expiry_datetime, ticket_name, ticket_price)
    VALUES ("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s") """ % (vrm, location_id, entryDatetime, expiryDatetime, "RINGOtest",SessionCost)
print sql_local
cursor.execute(sql_local)
```